# Django маршрут к apps

Tags: python, django

Какие настройки прописать в config.py, чтобы можно было поместить все приложения в папку apps?

Comment: Если у вас мало опыта в Python (а раз вы задали этот вопрос, значит опыта мало), то это не очень хорошая идея, так как Django не рассчитан на помещение приложений в дополнительные папки и могут случаться глюки

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете Django то менеджмент всех ваших приложение происходит в файле setting.py , а именно переменная INSTALLED_APPS.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Допустим вы создаёте приложение путём вызова команды :

```
python manage.py startapp polls
```

И она у вас появляется на ряду со всеми папками.

```
pools
mysite (*)
__init__.py
manage.py
```

- при условии ранее созданого проекта через команду **django-admin startproject mysite**

И если я правильно вас понял, вы хотите сделать некую папку apps , в которой будет не одно приложение (по типу pools), тогда создаёте просто такую папку, создаёте в ней файл

```
__init__.py
```

и перемещаете туда все свои приложения.

И теперь в настройках , в переменную INSTALLED_APPS добавляете

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'apps.pools',
    'apps.pools2',
    ... and other
]
```

Но учтите, что для версии Django==3.2.* в каждом проекте, вам придётся в файле apps.py каждого вашего приложение изменить переменную name.

(до перемещения в папку apps)

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
class PoolsConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'pools'
```

(после перемещения в папку apps)

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
class PoolsConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'apps.pools'
```